# InnerHTML doesn't work - Advanced function

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

I'm beginner in JS. But, after many hours, i'm really close to the wanted result.

I declare my JS Function in head part

```
function getPrice(price) {
var tabPrice = price.split("");
var html = "";
var virguleIndex = null;
for (var index = 0; index < tabPrice.length; ++index) {
    var priceNumber = tabPrice[index];
    if (priceNumber == ',') {
        virguleIndex = index;
        html += "<span class='p-c'>" + priceNumber + "</span>";
    } else if (priceNumber == '-') {
        html += "<span class='p-d'>" + priceNumber + "</span>";
    } else if (index > virguleIndex && virguleIndex != null) {
        html += "<span class='p-" + priceNumber + " p-small'>" + priceNumber + "</span>";
    } else {
        html += "<span class='p-" + priceNumber + "'>" + priceNumber + "</span>";
    }
}
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
div[0].innerHTML = html;
}
```

and my div in body part

```
<div class="price"></div>
```

---

I made some test - And my function getPrice works perflectly 
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/02/4/1515663887-functionwork.jpg

Some, the only fail (I think) is that the innerHTML don't work and don't write de var html content in div class price.

I haven't idea yet after many (many) hours of looking.

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance,

Ludovic

Comment: Can you create a working snippet using `<>` demonstrating how you are invoking the getPrice method?

Comment: var div = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
div[0].innerHTML = html; these line is working perfectly fine,. if you have a content in a variable html

Comment: Can you give a `console.log(html)` just above the `div[0].innerHTML = html;`

Comment: ok got your point. you are calling your function but your DOM is not ready. so please call your function after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: There is no function call here... Chances are you are calling this function before the dom is loaded.

Comment: Hello, Thank for your answer ! I'm not sure what are you talking about but the method is called lines below -> http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/02/4/1515666085-snippet.jpg Thanks again !

Comment: Wow, some many responses :D Thank everybody. With console log -> http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/02/4/1515666296-consolelog.jpg i've this result, looks good

Comment: I'll take a look on DOM loading ! :-) Keep you update ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  By going through your image it is clear your DOM is not ready. So Please call your function inside this Block.
 (function() {
    // your page initialization code here
    // the DOM will be available here
    //Call Your function inside this block. it will work ex. getPrice("100");

 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some news (I worked on this few hours), I check for the dom charging. I tried (thank for you answer) the call function / transpose the code and the end / forcing the function after the dom loading (with document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {)

Console log still working. But my div still empty :/

Thanks again !